# I want to make a video using all images which is generated in the 'for loop.' in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, video, matlab-figure

I am running a loop which generate an image `fg_modify` inside loop. i.e. the image is generated inside loop every time with same name and get over-written in next run. I want to make a video using all these images. Please help me.

```
for i=1:numframes 

    %blah blah 
    %blah blah
    %some code
    figure; imshow(fg_modify,[]) 

end
```

I want to make a video using all images `fg_modify` which is generated in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part has to go behind your plot in the loop:

```
plot(x,y)
drawnow
F(i) = getframe(fig)
```

And then you can play the movie afterwards

```
fig = figure;
movie(fig,F,2)
```

This would repeat the movie twice

You can find more at:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html

An Example:

```
for i=1:10
    x=1:10
    y=1:10
    y=y*i
    plot(x,y)

M(i)=getframe;

end 
movie(M,5)
```

Comment: It's showing error

Error using movie (line 40)
Movie contains uninitialized frames

Answer (score 0):

Use MuPad:

plot(plot::Line3d([0, 0, 0], [a, a, 1], a = 0..1),
     plot::Line3d([1, 0, 0], [a, 0, 1], a = 1..0))

To start video click on picture [image: To start video click on picture], or choose start on menu [image].

Than right click on image to save video. Choose .avi file format.

Comment: MuPad requires the Symbolic Mathematics Toolbox. Can you suggest a method without using this toolbox?